# Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1, model, fatal-error, customer-address

I am new to magento, I have a custom module for product advertising by registered user. When user check the phone check-box for adding phone number to Default Billing address (if not added the phone number already), it's return an error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object
```

[image]

My code is,

```
if (isset($_POST['request_flag'])):
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail();
$firstName = $customer->getFirstname();
$lastName = $customer->getLastname();
$fullName = $firstName . " " . $lastName;
$sellerId = $customer->getentity_id();

$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$newProduct = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

if (isset($_POST['phone_check'])) { //save phone no to customer's address
    $customerAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
    if ($customerAddressId) {
        $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
        $customAddress->setTelephone($params['phone']);
    }
    try {
        $customAddress->save(); //**Error occurred here.**
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please, any one tell me where I went wrong? or suggest me to what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it coming in "if ($customerAddressId) { }" in this condition ?

Comment: Yes, it is in "if ($customerAddressId) { }"

Comment: @PkRay added answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  if (isset($_POST['request_flag'])){
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $email = $customer->getEmail();
    $firstName = $customer->getFirstname();
    $lastName = $customer->getLastname();
    $fullName = $firstName . " " . $lastName;
    $sellerId = $customer->getentity_id();

    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $newProduct = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

    if (isset($_POST['phone_check'])) { //save phone no to customer's address
       try {
           $customerAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
           if ($customerAddressId) {
                $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
                $customAddress->setTelephone($params['phone']);
                $customAddress->save(); //**Error occurred here.**
           }

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code solved the Fatal error problem but the checked phone no not added to customer's Billing address. 
Please suggest, how can I add phone number to the billing address when the check-box is checked.

Comment: Are you getting address in $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId); ?

Comment: I've checked that, $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId); create Fatal error when the code looks like $customerAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
           if ($customerAddressId) {
                $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
           } that the echo $customAddress; show fatal error. But instead of that it show the user address if user already added, $customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling(); otherwise no data in array.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code in your if condition.

```
if (isset($_POST['phone_check'])) { //save phone no to customer's address
   //$customerAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
   $customerId  = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
    if ($customerId) {
        $customdata = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($customerId );
        $customAddress= Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customdata->default_billing);
        $customAddress->setTelephone($params['phone']);

    }
     try{
         $customAddress->save(); //**Error occurred here.**
     }
     catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
     }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to load the object in your code. In this case, Magento will simply try to create a new address object which will fail as there are many required fields not present, including customer itself.